# Firebase: How to display unicode string variables?

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

Hello – I've recently started adding Firebase Remote Config support to my android app. However, I've come to realise that any unicode strings that I set in either the default config or the remote config, get rendered as is.
For example, say there's a key `currency` and I set its value to `\u20b9` - then my app renders it as-is, and *NOT* the rupee symbol (₹) like it should.

On a related note, how to have line feeds inserted into config values, such that when rendered, a line-feed is inserted and *not* the sequence - `\n`

Comment: So is the question to render these symbols in the app or inside the Firebase console?

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: Apparently - you need to render the symbols yourself on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Place `\n` in Firebase remote config. And in your code do

`yourstirng.replaceAll("\\n", '\n');`